# Can't import wx (wxPython Phoenix) into my script

Tags: python-2.7, user-interface, python-3.x, wxpython

I'm taking a course in Python, and the current assignment is to convert a previous assignment written in Python 2 (which used wxPython) to Python 3 (which needs Phoenix). I successfully installed Phoenix, and in the Py3 shell I can now import wx just fine. However, if I try to run my actually script, it immediately gets this error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\transferdrillPy3.py", line 10, in 
    class windowClass(wx.Frame):
NameError: name 'wx' is not defined

What's up with that?

Comment: It looks like you are running the script from a Python 2 directory. I thought you wanted to run it with Python 3?

Answer (score 0):

I tried going through my code and deleting every single "wx.", and now it works. I guess Phoenix doesn't need that.

Comment: What does this mean? You deleted the `wx` from `wx.Button` and `wx.Frame` or ? That should not work unless you did something like `from wx import *` which is **not** recommended!